# How to save updater and creator when using inline models in Django admin

Tags: django

I'm trying to use `save_formset()` function to save updator and creator in Django admin. The way I implemented `save_formset()` doesn't work properly. It just keeps updating `updated_by`. Like I used `change` argument in `save_model()`, I thought it's gonna be working properly if I do the same way in `save_formset()`. Did I miss something?

```
class ImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Image
    extra = 0
    readonly_fields = ('updated_by', 'created_by', 'updated_at', 'created_at', )


@admin.register(Store)
class StoreAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = StoreForm

    inlines = [
        ImageInline,
    ]

    ... 

    # For inline models
    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)

        # For deleting
        for obj in formset.deleted_objects:
            obj.delete()

        # For adding
        for f in formset.forms:
            obj = f.instance
            if obj.image or obj.url:
                if not change:
                    obj.created_by = request.user
                else:
                    obj.updated_by = request.user
                obj.save()

        formset.save()

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # adding the entry for the first time
        if not change:
            obj.created_by = request.user
        # updating already existing record
        else:
            obj.updated_by = request.user

        obj.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `save_formset()` will work if your inline instances were updated. `formset.save(commit=False)` will return updated instances. You can try like this:

```
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
    instances = formset.save(commit=False)
    for obj in instances:
        if obj.id:
            obj.created_by = request.user
        else:
            obj.updated_by = request.user
    formset.save()
```

Comment: Thank you. Using `id` or `pk` works, but still can't figure out why `change` doesn't work. :(

Comment: Change is for the form, not the formset